# My account was broken into and virtual items were stolen, customer support refuses to help

Tags: contract-law, internet

I have all the proof showing that my account was broken into , but they still refuse to give me my items back after opening multiple tickets. I only get the same copy and paste messages from their support team members. There is a restoration system in place as well , my one time restoration was never used and they still refuse to give me my items back.It is also said that ''Unless required by law'' they won't 100% give the items back. Do you guys have any clue what they mean by that? All the help is appreciated.

Comment: You _badly_ need to [edit] this question, otherwise it will be closed as "asking for legal advice" - You also haven't given enough details to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this based on contract law, one would have to know where the company is located, where you are located, and what the terms of use specify regarding jurisdiction and possible mandatory arbitration.

Next, you write that you have "all the proof" that your account was "broken into." Proof in a legal sense? I think you would be writing things differently if you had as court judgement in this regard. And how did it happen? In my experience, there are several scenarios:

- You were **tricked** into revealing your credentials, or **your own** computer was compromised to gain your credentials, or you re-used the same credentials on different systems and one of those was compromised. The most likely scenario by far.
- There was a security breach on the **site of the game company**, either revealing your credentials or allowing direct access.
- There was an accidental software bug on the site of the game company which affected your inventory.
- There was a deliberate software change on the site of the game company which affected your inventory, e.g. to improve play balance.

The latter three options are all *possible*, but the first option happens much more frequently. And from the viewpoint of the company, this is indistinguishable from you acting foolishly and losing it. The thief would have been acting with your credentials, after all.

And that is where the term you quote comes in. The company is in a contractual relationship with their customers, so they cannot disclaim **all** responsibility for everything that happens through their terms of service. In some jurisdictions, sneaking an illegal clause into the boilerplate terms of service weakens the legal force of the whole document, so they make this sort of disclaimer. But if lost things could be restored too easily, the thrill would go out of ownership.

Comment: security breach 100% , multiple players are experiencing the same issues as me and the support refuses to do anything about it unless ''forced by law'' to do so. Which makes 0 sense because I received in my email a verification code needed by the hacker to access the account with his location in a whole different country than mine. Multiple trades were completed with other players with my items , the trades are 100% unfair, i am giving 2 million in game value for 200-500 ish and they still refuse to open their eyes which is alarming. What can i do to force them to give them back to me.

Comment: @ValTate, your question has been closed as being off-topic. But several people being hit by criminals are no evidence that the breach was on the game site, it might as well have been several players being tricked by the same malware. You did not say which game this is (smart, BTW, not to post too much personal information on public sites), but this game seems to have significant numbers of users. If this affected a small part, it might not have been general.